# how does it effect s the result of json file when we change the array value

Tags: python, json, python-requests

why does the content of the repository changing when we change the value in the array from 0 to any other number "json_response['items'][0]"

```py
import requests
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories',params={'q':'requests+language:python'},)

json_response = response.json()

repository = json_response['items'][0]

print(f'Repository name: {repository["name"]}')
 
print(f'Repository description: {repository["description"]}')
```

Comment: json_response['items'] is an array of all matched result. `0` is first result, `1` is second result and so on. Are you asking that?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR
The JSON file is not changing your are just referencing a subset of the JSON.

You can try doing:

```py
print(json_repsonse['items'])
```

It will help you understand that the response json for the key: 'items' will return a huge list of different repository names as a list.

```py
type(json_response['items'])
```

returns type of list. So the '[0]' after it is just referencing the first item  (in your case the repository name) in the list. When you change it to [1] it will reference the second item in the list of repository names. Therefore the repository names are changing.